# prove convergence of a series given sum of a_n converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Given $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n$ is a convergent series, and $a_n \geq 0$ for all n. Show that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{5n+6}{n+1}a_n$ is also a convergent series.

I tried to use Monotone Convergence Thm, but I failed to find a bound for $t_n = \sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{5k+6}{k+1}a_k$. Any idea how to approach this? I'm taking my first analysis class, so it should be some basic proof..

Comment: Use the limit comparison test!

Comment: $\frac{5n+6}{n+1}=5+\frac{1}{n+1}<6$

Comment: Equivalence criteria is the fastest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{5n+6}{n+1}=5+\frac{1}{n+1}<6$
So: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5n+6}{n+1} a_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 6 a_n=6\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n<\infty$

Answer (score 0):

The given series is clearly $5\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n + \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_n}{n+1}$. Let $S=\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ and
$$ G=\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}^+ : a_n \leq \frac{1}{n(n+2)}\right\},\qquad B=\mathbb{N}^+\setminus G. $$
We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_n}{n+1} &=& \sum_{n\in G}\frac{a_n}{n+1} + \sum_{n\in B}\left(\frac{a_n}{2}-\frac{(n-1) a_n}{2n+2}\right) \\&\leq&\sum_{n\in G}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}+\sum_{n\in B}\frac{a_n}{2}-\sum_{n\in B}\frac{n-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}\\&\leq&\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_n}{2}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{S}{2},\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence as soon as $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ is a convergent series with non-negative terms,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{5n+6}{n+1}a_n \leq \frac{1}{4}+\frac{11}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n.$$